# How to add pipe to groovy exec command-line?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to get information on a specific commit.  How do I add a pipe to the command-line?

```
def getCommitLog(commit){
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        ignoreExitValue true
        workingDir 'my_dir'
        commandLine 'git', 'log', '--decorate', '|', 'grep', commit
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    def retval = stdout.toString().trim()
    return retval
```

It throws this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '|': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]
```

Comment: Can you show what the `exec` method look like?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a subshell: ['bash', '-c', '<entire command>']

```
exec {
    commandLine = ['bash', '-c', 'find build/ -iname log4j.xml | xargs ls -lh' ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try changing as below i.e., use list

from:

```
commandLine 'git', 'log', '--decorate', '|', 'grep', commit
```

to:

```
commandLine ['git', 'log', '--decorate', '|', 'grep', 'commit']
```

Comment: Cannot cast object git with class java.lang.String to class 'int'

Comment: Yeah I used this for the line with the above error i posted:

commandLine ['git', 'log', '--decorate', '|', 'grep', commit]